# What exactly is Dynamic Routing in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I have been all around internet about the dynamic routing of React. But I couldn't find anything which explains how it works and how it is different than static routing in every single sense.

I understood it pretty well how the things go when we want to render something in the same page using React-Route.

My question is how does it work when a whole new page is wanted to be rendered? Because in this case all the DOM inside that page has to be re-rendered. Thus would it be static routing? or still dynamic in some ways?

I hope I've been clear.
Thanks for the answers in advance, I appreciate!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - this site is a Q & A site, not really a discussion forum - I suggest trying things out and if you have problems, come back with specific questions.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I apologise if I have done anything wrong, my purpose was not really to discuss but just to understand the real difference between these two terms.

Comment: Since the answer you marked is vividly not correct, please consider changing answer mark to prevent misleading of other users.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't think the above explanation is correct for **Static** vs **Dynamic** routing.Also there is not much explanation in the web for it, but there is a very nice explanation in [React Router Docs.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)From the Docs

> If you’ve used Rails, Express, Ember, Angular etc. you’ve used static
>   routing. In these frameworks, you declare your routes as part of your
>   app’s initialization before any rendering takes place. React Router
>   pre-v4 was also static (mostly). Let’s take a look at how to configure
>   routes in express:

In Static routing, the routes are declared and it imported in the Top level **before rendering**.

Whereas in Dynamic routing

> When we say dynamic routing, we mean routing that takes place as your
>   app is rendering, not in a configuration or convention outside of a
>   running app.

So in Dynamic routing, the routing takes place **as the App is rendering**.
The examples explained in the above answer are both for static routing.

For Dynamic routing it is more like

```
const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        {/* here's a div */}
        <div>
        {/* here's a Route */}
        <Route path="/tacos" component={Tacos}/>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
)

// when the url matches `/tacos` this component renders
const Tacos  = ({ match }) => (
    // here's a nested div
    <div>
        {/* here's a nested Route,
            match.url helps us make a relative path */}
        <Route
        path={match.url + '/carnitas'}
        component={Carnitas}
        />
    </div>
)
```

First in **App** component only one route is declared `/tacos`.When the user navigates to `/tacos` the **Tacos** component is mounted and there the next route is defined `/carnitas`.So when the user navigates to `/tacos/carnitas`, the **Carnitas** component is mounted and so on.

So here the routes are initialized dynamically.

Comment: But we call it “Dynamic Routing”, which is quite different from the “Static Routing” you’re probably more familiar with.

Comment: Didn't got your statement?

Answer (score -2):

Use react-router and react-router-dom, and write something like this:

```
onSubmit((e) => {
e.preventDefault();
this.props.history.push('<url>')
}
```

so at any place you may run this line and go to another locations conditionaly

Comment: so what's the reasons to get minused?