# React Component not rendering on using react router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

I am working on a simple demo React project. I have a Home component which gets rendered when directly placed in `main.js` but when placed inside the `Router` in `Routes.js`, it is not rendered. Can anyone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

`main.js` file

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {App} from "./app/App";
import Routes from "./app/Routes";

render( <Routes />,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

`Routes.js` file

```
import React from "react";

import {
   BrowserRouter as Router,  
   Route, 
    Switch,
    } from "react-router-dom";

import {App} 
    from "./App";

import Home from "./components/Home";

export default function Routes(props) {

    console.log('Routes');
    return (
        <Router>
            <App>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact  component={Home} />
                </Switch>  
            </App>
       </Router>
    )
}
```

`App.js` file

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";

export class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log("App render");

        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Welcome to React </h1>
                <Header/>
            </div>          
        )      
    }
}
```

`Header.js` file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Header extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log("Header render");

        return (
            <div>
                <NavLink to="/" exact>
                    Home
                </NavLink>                                   
            </div>
       )
    }
}
```

`Home.js` file

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class Home extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log("Home render");

        return (
            <div> 
                <h2>Hello World!</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using App component as the wrapper of whole app, and defined the `Switch` as the children of App component, so you need to use `this.props.children` inside App.

Like this:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log("App render");
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Welcome to React </h1>
                <Header/>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>          
        )  
    }
}
```

Consider this example to make the whole picture more clear, if you write:

```
<App>
   <Home />
</App>
```

Means `Home` will get passed as children to App component, automatically it will not get rendered inside App, you need to put `this.props.children` somewhere inside App.

Comment: Thanks, buddy. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

With react-router-v4 which you seem to be using, it is possible to have dynamic Routing which means you can add the Routes within nested components and hence apart from the solution that @MayankShukla suggested you could also keep the `<Switch>` and other routes within `App` like

```
export default function Routes(props) {

    console.log('Routes');
    return (
        <Router>
            <App/>
       </Router>
    )
}

export class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log("App render");

        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Welcome to React </h1>
                <Header/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact  component={Home} />
                </Switch>  
            </div>          
        )      
    }
}
```

You could read more about the **[advantages of Dynamic Routing here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817305/advantages-of-dynamic-vs-static-routing-in-react/48960268#48960268)**