# Confusion between static and dynamic routing in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was learning React Router and also I encountered terms as static and dynamic routing. That is, I got that dynamic routing means routing that takes place as your app is rendering but I cannot get exactly what that means and the same is the case with static routing. Please can you guys explain in simple terms and, if possible with examples. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096518/what-exactly-is-dynamic-routing-in-reactjs

Comment: @MikeAbeln, hey Mike, yeah I read that answer, but really cannot get the meaning. Please can you explain very briefly?

Comment: The basic difference is that in static routing routes are treated more like app infrastructure - all declared upon the app's initialization. With dynamic routing, routes are components just like other React components. You can return them and use them in classes or functional components closer to where they are implemented in your apps file structure. It's slightly a matter of preference as you can still define them all at the app initialization or later when you need to use them - whichever you think is easier and more legible.